How to get the feedback factor of this system?
If I want to get the feedback factor β of this system, do I need to consider the capacitor connected to ground or just 100k/(5k+400k+100k)?



How to get the feedback factor of this system?

It is the signal fed-back to the inverting input compared to the output signal, \$V_O\$: -
$$\dfrac{100\text{ k}\Omega}{100\text{ k}\Omega+400\text{ k}\Omega}= 0.2$$
You don't consider the 5 kΩ or Cc because the output comes after that point and, those components can be regarded as internal to the non-ideal op-amp. However, if you are trying to uncover how stable the circuit is, you have to consider them.

The feedback function is independent on the selected output terminal. The feedback factor is part of the loop gain which determines the stability properties of the circuit. Hence, also the R-C lowpass must be taken into consideration.
If R1=5k R2=400k and R3=100k and for an ideal opamp, the feedback function is
Hf=[Zc/(Zc+R1)] * R3/(R2+R3) with Zc=(1/sC)||(R2+R3)

So if I want to find stability of closed loop gain Bode Plot with 1/β(s), 1/β(s) should be 1/[Zc/(Zc+R1)] * R3/(R2+R3)?

@yolopoi Yes - that`s correct because I have assumed that the open-loop gain Aol is infinity. However, it is to be noted that there is an alternative view: When we define node Vo as output of the gain stage without feedback, we have another feedback function (because the R1-C lowpass now is considered as part of the gain stage and the source resistance for the feedback signal is not zero anymore). However - of course, the loop gain is identical in both cases - and thats what matters only!
